# Why does my site use SSR on my custom domain but but client-side rendering in the vercel-generated domain?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

(For context I'm using next version 14.0.3, testing on chrome, and am using the hobby plan on Vercel for deployments)

So I have a site with a header containing some links to other pages (using nextjs' `<Link>` component). When I click on a link I expect the site to navigate to the page using client-side rendering (i.e. no page reload), which it does on the [vercel-generated domain](https://boon-we-gig.vercel.app/en/seoul). But on my [custom domain](https://www.boonwegig.com/en/seoul), it uses SSR instead (i.e. when I click on a link, the site makes a network request to fetch a new page from the server causing a page reload).

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? Is there some sort of DNS issue going on?

Thank you in advance, been banging my head against this all day.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.. this was happening because I added an [umami tracking event prop](https://umami.is/docs/track-events) to my `<Link>` component. This wasn't occurring in my non-prod environments because I configured umami to only collect events from my custom domain. wild stuff check your  props kids